# How do i go to a label below?

Tags: java

So i have this code and i want when the user types A to activate the while(attack) which has is below this code so it doesnt work with continue attack; I placed a label called attack: above while(attack) but it does not recognize it because it gets declared later on.

```
String M2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Name2 + "'s Turn. Here are your options\n 1.Invade \n 2.Buy \n 3.End Turn \n 4.Check Money Balance \n 5.Check Soldier Count \n 6.Citizen's Hapinness \n 7.Owned Islands \n 8.Check Rules", "Type the Number of the action you want to take place");
                    if (M2.equals("1")) {
                        String Inv=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Open up the map and Check the island that you are in! If you dont remember the islands name type B to go back and then go into Owned Islands and come back! Then see the attack option you have and choose where you want to attack.Type A to Attack");
                        if(Inv.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
                            Attack=false;
                            Attack=true;
                            continue attack;
                        }else{

                            continue P2Menu2;
                        }
                    }
```

This is the code that has to start when the player types A. Thank you for your time.. :)

```
 //Attack Phase    
        attack:
        while (Attack) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int R = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int R2 = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int R3 = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int R4 = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int R5 = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int R6 = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
        int totalr[] = {R, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6};
```

Comment: Try to avoid cont/break with labels as much as you can. You are using it in improper way. If you can paste your whole code then it might be easier to see what you are doing.

Comment: put your while loop inside a method and then you can call it whenever you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Labels don't work like this. In Java, there is no `goto label` functionality. Labels are used when you have inner loops and you need to `break` or `continue` an outer loop, like in the following example:

```
outterloop:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // this would break the inner loop and go to the next outter loop iteration
        // break; 

        // this would break the outter loop, thus exiting both loops
        // break outterloop; 

        // this would jump to the next inner loop iteration
        // continue; 

        // this would jump to the next outter loop iteration, exiting the inner loop
        // continue outterloop; 
    }
}
```

What you need is to improve your code structure to achieve what you want without the need of labels.

---

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html